How can I remove the noise on metal surfaces in Eevee?
I'm new to blender, I followed a tutorial on how to model this boombox but now I have a problem with the metal surface on the logo. I know how to remove the noise in cycles but since it is a video I need to render it in eevee.


Here is an example of my rendered video where the noise looks more obvious.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=csmJU18CBC8

did you try to increase the samples? if this doesn't help, pls provide blend file

@Chris increasing samples didn't work. Here I leave the blend file if you want to check it: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/14ohBMJgBCtbv9x5KWG9PNWqqHQ-z5bPi

what sample count did u use?

this blend file doesn't fit to the image you provided...that's how it looks, when i rendered it: [1]: https://i.sstatic.net/Kn87ti3G.png

@Chris My bad, I forgot to share the textures and the hdri. Here is the updated file. You will have to download the blend file again for the texture file paths to update correctly.
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1QJoWYw8Uy89wlmSmJI9MThCdg4iXPuhx?usp=drive_link   By the way, I increased the samples in subsurface scattering to 32 and in volumetrics to 64, if that's what you mean.
